# Does blender drain battery life when I'm not using it?

Tags: osx

I used Avid Media Composer for a few weeks on my laptop, but it drained a lot of battery without me using it. Will blender do the same?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are rendering or have an active process (like generating a simulation), blender won't run in the Background on your Computer, so it shouldn't drain any Battery